# How to place text and image inside a shape with HTML?

Tags: html, css, image, text, shapes

I'm trying to teach myself HTML, and I've been stuck on this. I'm basically trying to place a web image on top of a solid black rectangle created in HTML. The rectangle should have enough room for text on the top and bottom, and be aligned to the right of the page. Ideally, it should look just like this. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBRrB.png)

Comment: Well show us what you've tried so far, and maybe we can close the gap between where you are and where you want to get to

Comment: Please take the [tour], and read the guidance about posting “*[mcve]*” code, and “*[ask].*”

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this as a starting point:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.card {
width: 200px;
background-color: #000;
color: #fff;
padding: 20px 40px;
}
a {
color: #fff;
}
h1 {
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="card">
<h1>TEXT HERE</h1> 
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="image">
<h2>Some text with a <a href="https://example.com">link</a>.</h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Further reading: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_cards.asp